# What are the red and green bars under my weapon on the HUD?

Tags: doom-2016

In the bottom right (underneath my weapon) it shows 3 green bars and 7 red bars - what do these represent? The same bars are displayed regardless of which weapon I have equipped.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The green bar indicates the number of rounds for your BFG 9000, and the red bar indicates the amount of fuel for your Chainsaw.

Comment: It's worth noting that your BFG 9000 only consumes one "bar" of ammunition per shot, put your chainsaw may consume multiple "bars" of fuel depending on the enemy slay with it.